# Powerform Online and Salesforce Send Not working together

Tags: docusignapi

Here's my scenario:

I have a Powerform that people sign online and I am passing AccountID parameters to a custom tag called AccountID on the form with no problems at all.  In my DocuSign connect settings for Salesforce, I have it mapped to Account ID (SF) and AccountID (custom tag). This is working perfectly right now.

A problem came up because I want users to be able to send that same powerform out of Salesforce as well.  I am using the custom send agreement code in Docusign documentation but it is not allowing me to pass any parameters to it.

So in my connect settings, my where clause says Account ID (SF) and AccountID (custom tag) works for my online powerform but NOT for my SFDC sends.

If I change my connect settings where clause to say Account ID (SF) and Envelope Source ID(docusign), then this works for my SFDC sends but not for my online signers.

Screenshot from Comment
This setting works for my online powerform
[image]

This setting works with my SFDC button
[image]

Additional Config
[image]

Anyone have any solutions to this?

Thank you!!!

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your connect configuration including the bottom part? (edit out the email and username list please)

Comment: Stackoverflow says I can't post any images.

Comment: host it somewhere and I'll edit it in, it's due to your rep

Comment: https://awana.box.com/s/8hmntk3mdcn8vwc6q6lmv7z7gb2r8dyx

Comment: Added images. Does your Powerform have the Salesforce Object ID in a field somewhere?

Comment: I have the AccountID custom tag on my powerform but I can't pass values to it using SFDC Send Agreement button.  I tried passing to the Envelope_FieldDSFSSourceObjectID field but it was not working and linking back the signed document to my salesforce